# Array iteration: Rewriting forEach loop to for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays

For an exercise I have to rewrite this forEach loop into a for loop:

```
var numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];

numbers.forEach(function(number){
  if(number % 3 === 0) {
   console.log(number);
  }
});
```

I came up with the following but it didn't really work as it gave me undefined:

```
        var numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];

        for(var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        if(numbers % 3 === 0) {
        console.log(numbers);
        } 
    };
```

Could somebody explain to me what went wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to the the `i-th`(current one) element of `numbers`:

```js
var numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
for(var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    if(numbers[i] % 3 === 0) {
           // ^^^---here
        console.log(numbers[i]);
           //              ^^^---here
    } 
};
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if(numbers[i] % 3 === 0) {
     console.log(numbers[i]);
 }
```

Comment: console.log(numbers[i]) you mean

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the i-th element of numbers.

```js
     var numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];

        for(var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        if(numbers[i] % 3 === 0) {
        console.log(numbers[i]);
        } 
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

function fun(number) {
  if (number % 3 === 0) {
    console.log(number);
  }
}

// Your code with `forEach` 
numbers.forEach(fun);

// Same with for-loop when convert
for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
  fun(numbers[i]);
}

// you are using `numbers % 3`, numbers is an array and you actually you wanted to use with number (which will be `numbers[i]`
```